# ¿como puedo configurar para que el servidor me tome local time, ubuntu server?

Tags: apache, mariadb, ubuntu-server

estoy usando mariadb, el cual en algunos campos lo tengo configurado para que me tome
la hora actual, cada que haya un registro.

pero tengo un problema me esta tomando la hora universal time:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me esta tomando es la hora universal time, la que me debe tomar es la local time zone.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si debo configurar alguna otra cosa, en mariadb, apache o ubuntu,
agradezco sus ayudas.

Answer (score 0):

Sigue la [documentación](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/time-zones/) y configura tu instancia de MariaDB para que use el time_zone correcto.

Comienza por revisar cómo está actualmente, que puede ser algo así

```
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| time_zone     | SYSTEM |
+---------------+--------+
```

Luego puedes probar con

`SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/New_York';`

y volver a revisar las SESSION VARIABLES. Para que el cambio perdure entre reinicios, configura esta opción en uno de los [archivos de servicio](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/) de la BD (hace un rato que no uso MySQL, pero `/etc/my.cnf` suele ser el camino para que sea una configuración global).